# Django Model Modification missing field:

Tags: django

I am trying to add and "orders" field to a user that is a foreignkey to a class Order. Order has a foreignkey to a class OrderItem. OrderItem has a OneToOneField to another app's class Store Item. I used south to migrate the database. I do not believe the error is in the way the database was migrated. I get an operational error, "error: no such table: webstore_storeitem". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from loginRouter import *



class OrderItem(models.Model):
      itemCost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2)
      itemQuantity = models.IntegerField()
      itemID = models.OneToOneField('webstore.StoreItem')
      def __unicode__(self):
            return  self.itemID.itemName


class Order(models.Model):

      orderDate = models.DateTimeField('Order Date')
      shippingCost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2)
      totalCost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2)
      item = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem)
      def __unicode__(self):
            return  unicode(self.item)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User)
      confirmation_code = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      reset_code = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      address_lineOne = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      address_lineTwo = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      State = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
      orders = models.ForeignKey(Order)
      def __unicode__(self): 
            return self.user.username
```

What I did with south:

```
before Change:
$./manage.py schemamigration login --initial
after change:
$./manage.py schemamigration login --auto
$./manage.py migrate login --fake
$./manage.py migrate login
```

webstore.Models:

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class StoreCategory(models.Model):
  categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.categoryName 

class StoreItem(models.Model):

  category = models.ForeignKey(StoreCategory)
  itemName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  itemNameid = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
  picture = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='avatars',
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(250, 185)],
                                       format='JPEG',
                                       options={'quality': 60})
  featured_picture = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='avatars',
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(800, 300)],
                                       format='JPEG',
                                       options={'quality': 60})
  isFeatured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return  self.itemName
```

Comment: can you include the full track of the error? Also, can you include the class that is connected with OrderItem by the OneToOneField?

Comment: By doing `./manage.py migrate login --fake` the migrations are forwarded, and tables are not created.. You probably meant to do `./manage.py migrate login --fake 0001`

Comment: I got the other model added. Im not sure what you mean by track, I'm sorry. @karthikr: I also blew out the database and created it again. Also, I just thought of something each model(for each app) is using a separate database.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that each app was using a separate database. I merged them and this resolved the problem I was having.